# Dynamic importing a library next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lazy-loading, next.js, dynamic-import

I am trying to import a [library](https://github.com/retejs/connection-reroute-plugin) dynamically in one of my next.js project. When i try to import that in don't get the default export from the library as expected. Firstly, i tried the next.js way as:

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const ConnectionReroutePlugin = dynamic(() => import('rete-connection-reroute-plugin'), { ssr: false });
```

Then i tried the react way as:

```
const ConnectionReroutePlugin = React.lazy(() => import('rete-connection-reroute-plugin'));
```

I am seeing the following import error:

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): plugin.install is not a function

Anyone can address, what i am doing wrong and how can i import that?

Comment: Why don't you just `import ConnectionReroutePlugin from 'rete-connection-reroute-plugin'`?

Comment: That's not my question actually.

Comment: Try using .default to import a default export, e.g. const lib = await import('path/to/lib').default

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is you need to pass import as a loader. like following

```
const ConnectionReroutePlugin = dynamic({
  loader: () => import("rete-connection-reroute-plugin"),
  ssr: false
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that doesn't works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.onload = function () {
 // do something here
};
script.src = something;

document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: Thanks for the approach. But i am looking a react way not vanilla javascript.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make a dynamic import of a library, you can do

```
import('rete-connection-reroute-plugin')
  .then(({ default: ConnectionReroutePlugin }) => /*  do what you want */)
```

also, async/await syntax can be used.